# Getting access to chart_Series () from the quantmod package

Tags: r, package, quantmod

The R quantmod package documentation describes both the chartSeries() and chart_Series() functions. But after requiring quantmod, only the chartSeries() function is available. Is there a special way to get access to an R package function besides install.packages() or update.packages()?

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate the problem running Mac 10.5.8 with R 2.12.0 and quantmod_0.3-14. Both functions have a help page and both the function parameter lists and bodies appear when their names are typed at the console. Are you running an up-to-date version of R with the latest version of quantmod?

Comment: Mac OSX 10.6.4. R base "2.12.0". quantmod "0.3-14" hmmmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of quantmod are you using?  `chart_Series` is exported in quantmod_0.3-14 (on CRAN).  If you're using an earlier version of quantmod, the `chart_Series` function may not be exported.  In that case, you can access it via `quantmod:::chart_Series`.

---

Update:
I'm not intimately familiar with the differences between 32- and 64-bit R on OSX, but you could try to re-install quantmod using 64-bit R if you initially installed it with 32-bit R.

Comment: installed.packages() says quantmod "0.3-14"rom And when I type chartSeries in the R console, I get the function. But when I type chart_Series I get: Error: object 'chart_Series' not found

Comment: I didn't mention I'm using OSX R64. And lo and behold when I run the regular R in OSX (32 bit version I presume), there is the chart_Series function. Of course, this begs the question of why chart_Series is available on 32-bit R and not 64-bit R.